# Redefining objective function to incorporate x-axis

Tags: statistics, optimization, standard-deviation, constraints

I recently asked a question about minimizing the standard deviation from a list of equidistant values and I received a great answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4089367/907708

However, now I am tasked with redefining the first equation in the answer to the above question to allow for an x-axis, (points are no longer equidistant).

At this point, I am now given an x-axis that must remain fixed. (standard deviation must still be optimized but now we are given another constraint that points on the x-axis are no longer equidistant and therefore they must factor into the equation somehow ).

The points along the x-axis must remain fixed but the points on the y-axis are still free to be moved within the bounds defined in the previous question.

I was hoping someone could help me redefine the objective function in the above answer, or at least help point me in the right direction.

Example:
`y = [20, 24, 28, 24 ,20 ,18, 20, 32 ,30, 28, 20 ,24]` (this is the `h` from the previous question)

`x = [10,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,70,80]`

This is not a homework problem so therefore I have no course material to help guide me to an answer. The only guidance I have is from the comments and answers to this post. Please understand that I am in no way a mathematician so I really need all the help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: In your example, are you trying to minimize the standard deviation of the resulting list of 23 numbers?

Comment: We are trying to minimize the standard deviation of the 12 numbers in the y array.

Comment: Then what do the $x$ values matter?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify, we are trying to minimize the point to point standard deviation while keeping the x values constant and only changing the y values. We are trying to minimize the standard deviation of the list of points as a whole. Sorry if I didn't make that clear in the initial question.

Comment: Standard deviation of distances between all $\binom{n}{2}$ pairs of points or just $n-1$ pairs of consecutive points?

Comment: I believe it should be all ( 2) pairs of points

Answer (score 1):

For the original data, the standard deviation of the Euclidean distances between all $\binom{12}{2}=66$ pairs of points is $15.29$.  By perturbing $y$ to

```
[22, 24, 30, 26, 20, 18, 20, 34, 32, 28, 20, 25.84]
```

you can reduce the standard deviation to $15.08$.

[image]

I obtained this solution by solving a nonlinear optimization problem to minimize the standard deviation of distances $d_{i,j}$ subject to
\begin{align}
d_{i,j} &= \sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^2+(y_i'-y_j')^2} &&\text{for all $1\le i<j \le n$}\\
y_i' &\in [y_i,y_i+2] &&\text{for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$}
\end{align}

---

If you instead consider only consecutive pairs $(i,i+1)$, the original standard deviation is $3.14$, and by perturbing $y$ to

```
[22, 24, 30, 26, 22, 18, 22, 32, 32, 28, 22, 24]
```

you can reduce the standard deviation to $2.34$.
[image]

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for, however, I was wondering if you had a formula you could share with me that helped you arrive at your answer.

Comment: Also, if it's not too much, could you also show me how this answer would change if you were trying to reduce the standard deviation of the n-1 consecutive points instead of the (12 2) points.