# Minimize euclidean distance in relation to horizontal distance for a series of points by only adjusting y axis

Tags: statistics, optimization, euclidean-geometry, constraints

So I have sort of a niche question for a personal project I have been working on for some time now and I was hoping someone could help me gain a little insight as to how to proceed.

**Situation:**

I am trying to come up with an algorithm that minimizes the euclidean distance from point to point to be as close as possible to the horizontal distance from point to point with the constraint that each element on the y axis can be incremented by an amount within a set of bounds.

**Example:**

I have a series of points on a 2D graph with a immutable x axis,
`x = [10,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,70,80]`

and a mutable y axis `y = [20, 24, 28, 24 ,20 ,18, 20, 32 ,30, 28, 20 ,24]`

I also have the constraint that each point in `y` can be raised by a c value anywhere from 0 to 2.

I am trying to come up with an algorithm that minimizes the euclidean distance from point to point to be as close as possible to the horizontal distance from point to point with the constraint that each element in `y` can be raised by `0 <= c <= n` for a `y` of any length with any values and with any `n > 0`.

**EDIT:** To be clear, I want to minimize the difference between the euclidean distance and horizontal distance between all adjacent points. The constraints are that we can move each point in `y` up independently by anywhere between 0 and 2 units. We cannot however, change the `x` values.

I am very new to optimization problems and although I have seen problems that look similar to my question, I have not seen any that I've been able to gather enough information to help push me further towards an answer.

If possible, I was hoping someone would help me define the objective function, constraints, and other necessary functions that would lead me to an answer.

This is not a homework problem so therefore I have no course material to help guide me to an answer. The only guidance I have is from the comments and answers to this post. Please understand that I am in no way a mathematician so I really need all the help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: I think you are going to have to be clearer. What exactly is the quantity you are trying to minimize? You say you want to minimize something to be close to something else, which is somewhat inconsistent. You need to say "I want to minimize this quantity" then separately say "these are the constraints on that quantity".

Comment: I want to minimize the difference between the euclidean distance and horizontal distance between all adjacent points. The constraints are that we can move each point in y up independently by anywhere between 0 and 2 units.

Comment: If the only thing you can do is raise each $y$ by some value between $0$ and $n$, raising some of the $y$ values will help you for the distance on one side while hurting on the other side. For this to be a well-posed problem, you need some way of determining how these two changes compare. For instance, you could minimize the sum of the distances between all adjacent points (the length of the polygonal curve connecting them). That is a well-defined goal. But "minimize all the distances" is not well-defined.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Did you know of any way to minimize the sum of the distances between all adjacent points?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redefining objective function to incorporate x-axis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4116249/redefining-objective-function-to-incorporate-x-axis)

Comment: @RobPratt I was the original poster of that question . But no it didn't do the full job of answering the question.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you are trying to ask a different question here, but they look very similar.  Do you maybe want to adjust the $y_i$ values to minimize the sum of the $n-1$ Euclidean distances?

Comment: I am asking a very similar question here with the same intent as the first question. I just don't think the answer to the last question was the answer I was looking for. And yes I think adjusting the  values to minimize the sum of the −1 Euclidean distances is possibly what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to minimize the sum of Euclidean distances
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{(x_i-x_{i+1})^2+(y_i'-y_{i+1}')^2}$$
subject to
$y_i' \in [y_i,y_i+2]$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.
The initial sum of distances is $88.097$, and by perturbing $y$ to

```
[22, 26, 28, 25, 22, 20, 22, 32, 30, 28, 22, 24]
```

you can reduce the sum of distances to $82.398$.

[image]

---

By request, here is the SAS code:

```
data indata;
   input x y;
   datalines;
10 20
20 24
25 28
30 24
35 20
40 18
45 20
50 32
55 30
60 28
70 20
80 24
;

proc optmodel;
   set POINTS;
   num x {POINTS};
   num y {POINTS};
   read data indata into POINTS=[_N_] x y;

   var C {POINTS} >= 0 <= 2;
   impvar Yprime {i in POINTS} = y[i] + C[i];
   min Z = sum {i in 1..card(POINTS)-1} sqrt((x[i]-x[i+1])^2+(Yprime[i]-Yprime[i+1])^2);

   solve;

   create data outdata from [i] x y C Yprime;
quit;

proc sgplot data=outdata noautolegend;
   scatter x=x y=y;
   vector x=x y=Yprime / xorigin=x yorigin=y lineattrs=(color=red);
run;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this great answer, I think this is exactly what I was looking for. I was wondering however, which coding language (or software) you used to get this answer.  I was hoping you could share your code with me if its not too much to ask?

Comment: Glad to help.  I added the SAS code just now.  Please mark my answer as accepted.